# how to clear the output after first line in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I need to make some input tests. I cant figure out how to clear the output place after i check the first number for example. Also, could you help me figuring out how to seperate two if's, if the conditions work on the same number, but i need to output one condition. for example, i need to make that if the number -3 is a negative value, the output should show "reikalingas teigiamas skaičius", but it shows this and " gautas skaičius iš netinkamo intervalo ".

```js
function fun() {
  let a = document.getElementById('kodas').value;
  let g = "";
  let fig = "";
  switch (a) {
    case "3":
      fig = "trikampis";
      break;
    case "4":
      fig = "keturkampis";
      break;
    case "5":
      fig = "penkiakampis";
      break;
    case "6":
      fig = "sesiakampis";
      break;
    case "7":
      fig = "septynkampis";
      break;
    case "8":
      fig = "astuonkampis";
      break;
    case "9":
      fig = "devynkampis";
      break;

  };

  if (a == " " || a == "") {
    document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = " nieko neįvesta ";
  }

  if (isNaN(a)) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = " gautas ne skaicius ";
  }

  if (a < 3 || a > 9) {
    document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = " gautas skaičius iš netinkamo intervalo ";
  }

  if (a < 0) {
    document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = " reikalingas teigiamas skaicius ";
  }

  if (Number.isInteger(a)) {
    document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = " gautas ne sveikasis skaicius ";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('demo4').innerHTML = fig;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="kodas" type="text">
<button onclick="fun()">Įvesti</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>
<p id="demo5"></p>
```

Comment: on a side note you dont really require all those demo1, demo2, demo3 tags. you could use just one of them for everything. Check my example below.

Comment: im sorry, but it doesnt work for me, when i for e.x type in "trys" or "-3", it doesnt output anything

Comment: I have edited it , it works now for all cases , except "gautas ne sveikasis skaicius". Could you tell when should "gautas ne sveikasis skaicius" be shown.

Comment: "gautas ne sveikasis skaicius" should be shown if the number is not an integer, for example 4.5 ; 3.5

Comment: so if number is 2.5 which one to display - "gautas ne sveikasis skaicius"  or " gautas skaičius iš netinkamo intervalo "

Comment: if the number is 2.5 it should display "gautas ne sveikasis skaicius"

Comment: if it solves all , then please accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers both your questions:
for the code to display the proper -1

```js
function fun() {

  let a = document.getElementById('kodas').value;
  let g = "";
  let fig = "";
  switch (a) {
    case "3":
      fig = "trikampis";
      break;
    case "4":
      fig = "keturkampis";
      break;
    case "5":
      fig = "penkiakampis";
      break;
    case "6":
      fig = "sesiakampis";
      break;
    case "7":
      fig = "septynkampis";
      break;
    case "8":
      fig = "astuonkampis";
      break;
    case "9":
      fig = "devynkampis";
      break;

  };



  if (a == " " || a == "") {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = " nieko neįvesta ";
  } else if (isNaN(a)) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = " gautas ne skaicius ";
  } else if (a < 0) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = " reikalingas teigiamas skaicius ";
  } else if (!Number.isInteger(Number(a))) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = " gautas ne sveikasis skaicius ";
  } else if (a < 3 || a > 9) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = " gautas skaičius iš netinkamo intervalo ";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = fig;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="kodas" type="text">
<button onclick="fun()">Įvesti</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the start of your function:

```
const array = ['demo', 'demo1', 'demo2', 'demo3', 'demo4', 'demo5'];
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById(array[i]).innerHTML = '';
}
```